# Progress bar in dynamic fragment with adapter in view page Adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to show progress bar in a dynamic fragment with adapter which takes data from firebase real time database.

I am able to get data from firebase database in the fragments and set progress bar visibility to true if no data found in the firebase. But the progress bar shows only in the last fragment that dynamically created.

How to show progressbar in each fragment if no data found  ??

code that i tried inside create view of fragment

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        show_progress();

            if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                Hide_no_content_message();
                hide_progress();
                // data is found
              //call adapter with list of data and set adapter to recyclerview
            }
            else{

               /* If no data found do this */
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void run() {
                                                  hide_progress();
                                                  Show_no_content_message();  
                                              }
                                          },3000);}}
```

Comment: progressbar should be shown only if the data is getting fetched. why do you want it to appear even if no data is found?

Comment: Instead you could try showing an image or a text saying there is no data.!?

Comment: can you share what you have tried ?

Comment: Please also add the code that you are using.

Comment: @sanjeev  yes I tried to show progress bar for 3 sec and the hide it and show a text like you said.  fragments are added to a tablayout so progressbar and text shows only in the last tab.

Comment: code of what you have tried would be helpful like others suggest. cuz I do not know where you used the progressbar in a fragment or an activity. is all fragments part of the same activity?

Comment: @sanjeev edited  question with code. used same fragment using loop and used the above code in it's view and reference to firebase dynamically changed according to the fragment

Comment: Just hide the progressbar initially.. then when it comes into the loop use `progressbar.setVisiblity(View.Visible)` so once its completed it hides naturally?

Comment: @sanjeev  hide_progress(); and show_progress(); method set progressbar visibility to invisible/visible. Now i have 2 tabs Since i am using same fragment progressbar/text showing in the second tab not first tab.

Comment: Are you using the same progressbar from that fragment 1 and using it in fragment 2 and 3? cuz that is not possible unless you are using the fragments with same View(xml)..

Comment: @sanjeev i have only one fragment and added to viewpage adapter using a loop